# Correct use of simple past and past perfect

Tags: past-tense

I received a call which was for my colleague. he was not at his seat at that time hence I told caller I will inform him about his call once he returned to his seat.

How should I inform to my colleague?

Xyz had called you, Please call him

Or

Xyz called you, Please call him

I know there is one more way to say this

Xyz's call for you Please call him

According to me simple past is enough here because I want to refer only one past event.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Of your examples, 1) and 3) are incorrect. 1) would be ok if you changed it to

```
Xyz has called you: please call him.
```

... but 2) is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is closest. I would say:

> Xyz called you, please call him **back**.

or

> > Xyz called you, please **return** his call.

Simple present is correct in this example, since Xyz's call is now entirely in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatic would be

**You received a call from XYZ.**

or

**XYZ phoned while you were away from your desk.**

P.S. When explaining the situation to us, you should say

> I told **the** caller I **would** inform him once he returned to his
>   seat.

When explaining to us what you said, you are not directly quoting yourself ("will" is what you actually said) but reporting indirectly what you said, and so we backshift **will** to **would** to reflect that nuance.